# Adding toggle-able extra information to an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that compares this week to last week for our clients. (ignore the formatting it's a work in progress)

[image: 1st report]

I want to add in a breakdown by day of the week. Which is fine but the client list is 100+ long so having each one broken down by day of the week is unwieldy to say the least.

[image: 2nd report]

What I'm looking for is the 1st report but with an option for the user to expand any particular client they want and to see the daily breakdown for that client only. Is this possible in SSRS and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior using conditional visibility.

1. Make note of the name of the textbox that contains the client names.
2. Right-click on the textbox that has the day names and go to "Text Box Properties".
3. Go to the "Visibility" tab.
4. Select "Hide".
5. Select "Display can be toggled bu this report item" and select the textbox name that you made note of in step 1.
6. Click OK.

Now when the report runs the days will be collapsed but there will be a [+] symbol next to the client names to expand it.